# Подскажете как заполнить Sqlite базу данных из файла xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, sqlite

Мне требуется заполнять базу данных SQlite из xml файла, таблиц в базе данных 6 штук и xml файл несет в себе записи на все эти 6 таблиц

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<database name="npma_amawal" >
    <!-- Table wp_posts -->
    <table name="cat" >
        <column name="ID" >948</column>
        <column name="klic" >bos</column>
        <column name="color" >white</column>
    </table>
    <table name="dog" >
        <column name="ID" >46</column>
        <column name="klic" >Sharik</column>
        <column name="color" >black</column>
    </table>
</database>
```

Тут всего лишь для двух, но думаю что это не критично для какого количества, файл называется cat

Ниже представлен код вроде для заполнения одной таблицы

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

import com.example.myapplication.XMLParser;
import com.example.myapplication.XMLParserObject;

class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String DB_TEST = "amawal.sqlite";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "wp_posts";
    public static final String ID = "ID";
    public static final String post_content = "post_content";
    public static final String post_title = "post_title";
    private static Context mContext;
    List<XMLParserObject> posts = null;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_TEST, null, 1);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + ID + " INTEGER, " + post_content + " TEXT, "
                + post_title + " TEXT);");

        // Insert data from XML
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        try {
            posts = parser.parse(mContext.getAssets().open("cat"));

            for (XMLParserObject post : posts) {
                //Toast.makeText(mContext, post.getpostTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put(ID, post.getId());
                values.put(post_content, post.getPostContent());
                values.put(post_title, post.getpostTitle());
                db.insert(TABLE_NAME, ID, values);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: ребята, вы все с одних курсов. пользуйтесь поисковиком. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1134927/%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-csv-%d0%b2-sqlite

Comment: так там другой тип файла

Comment: сегодня вам задали парсить xml, потом json, а потом еще и  csv и все это сохранять в бд. отличие только в том, какую библиотеку подключать. для csv я показал. поменяйте это на Gson и спарсите джейсоны, аналогично для xml. или я чего-то не понимаю? а если сделаете общий интерфейс для приведенного мной сервиса, то только реализации будете подбрасывать, вообще не важно, что парсить.

Comment: Я просто в этом не особо разбираюсь поэтому и спрашиваю, там в примере приводится данные для одной таблицы, но у меня их несколько, это сильно будет отличаться?

Comment: вообще не будет отличаться. прочитайте внимательно все, что я написал в ответе. под каждую таблицу вам нужно добавлять класс-модель и все

Comment: Подскажите как заполнить базу данных коллекцией объектов?

Comment: для этого используются классы ServiceImpl, BaseServiceImpl, BookService. там есть метод saveAll, принимающий лист объектов

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, как это работает. Вот мой вопрос с кодом который я сделал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135280/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-sqlite

Comment: работает это без цепочки условных операторов))) но не суть... сделали парсер - уже хорошо, а в чем вопрос то? сохранение в базу описано у меня в ответе

Comment: Вы там просто используете всякие библиотеки наверно, они нужны для svc файла, а у меня xml

Comment: нет, для csv нужен только compile group: 'au.com.bytecode', name: 'opencsv', version: '2.4' остальное орм, логирование, ломбок (для генерации стандартных методов). я строю то, что называется сервис леер. это паттерн такой. плюс я использую орм