# Как добавить коллекцию объектов в базу данных SQLite&

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, arraylist

Я сделал чтение из файла xml, преобразовал записи в объекты, теперь мне требуется добавить их в базу данных для последующей работы с ней.

В данном классе я преобразую в коллекцию

```
package Models;

import android.os.Build;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

public class DOMExample {
 // Коллекция для хранения всех людей
 private static ArrayList<Errors> errors = new ArrayList<>();

 // Константы для элементов
 private static final String BackBrakePressureEmergency = "BackBrakePressureEmergency";
 private static final String CloggedSteeringFilters = "CloggedSteeringFilters";
 private static final String CloggedSteeringFiltersGS = "CloggedSteeringFiltersGS";
 private static final String EmergencyOil = "EmergencyOil";
 private static final String EmergencyOilLevelGS = "EmergencyOilLevelGS";
 private static final String FontBrakePressureEmergency = "FontBrakePressureEmergency";

 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
     // Получение фабрики, чтобы после получить билдер документов.
     DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

     // Получили из фабрики билдер, который парсит XML, создает структуру Document в виде иерархического дерева.
     DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

     // Запарсили XML, создав структуру Document. Теперь у нас есть доступ ко всем элементам, каким нам нужно.
     Document document = builder.parse(new File("resource/xml_file3.xml"));

     // Получение информации про каждый элемент отдельно
     collectInformation(document, BackBrakePressureEmergency);
     collectInformation(document, CloggedSteeringFilters);
     collectInformation(document, CloggedSteeringFiltersGS);
     collectInformation(document,EmergencyOil);
     collectInformation(document,EmergencyOilLevelGS);
     collectInformation(document,FontBrakePressureEmergency);

     // Вывод информации
     errors.forEach(System.out::println);
 }

 /**
  * Метод ищет информацию про теги по имени element и вносит всю информацию в коллекцию humans.
  * @param document Документ, в котором будем искать элементы.
  * @param element Имя элемента, теги которого нужно найти. Должна быть одна из констант, которые определяются выше.
  */
 private static void collectInformation(Document document, final String element) {
     // Получение всех элементов по имени тега.
     NodeList elements = document.getElementsByTagName(element);

     // Перебор всех найденных элементов
     for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
         // Получение всех атрибутов элемента
         NamedNodeMap attributes = elements.item(i).getAttributes();
         String startDate = attributes.getNamedItem("startDate").getNodeValue();
         String endDate = attributes.getNamedItem("endDate").getNodeValue();
         int duration =Integer.parseInt(attributes.getNamedItem("duration").getNodeValue());

         // В зависимости от типа элемента, нам нужно собрать свою дополнительну информацию про каждый подкласс, а после добавить нужные образцы в коллекцию.
         switch (element) {
             case BackBrakePressureEmergency: {
                 int turnover =Integer.parseInt(attributes.getNamedItem("turnover").getNodeValue());
                 errors.add(new BackBrakePressureEmergency(turnover,startDate,endDate,duration));
             } break;
             case CloggedSteeringFilters: {
                 errors.add(new CloggedSteeringFilters(startDate,endDate,duration));
             } break;
             case CloggedSteeringFiltersGS: {
                 errors.add(new CloggedSteeringFiltersGS(startDate,endDate,duration));
             } break;
             case EmergencyOil: {
                 int temp =Integer.parseInt(attributes.getNamedItem("temp").getNodeValue());
                 errors.add(new EmergencyOil(startDate,endDate,duration,temp));
                 break;
             }
             case EmergencyOilLevelGS: {
                 errors.add(new EmergencyOilLevelGS(startDate,endDate,duration));
             } break;
             case FontBrakePressureEmergency: {
                 int turnover =Integer.parseInt(attributes.getNamedItem("turnover").getNodeValue());
                 errors.add(new FontBrakePressureEmergency(turnover,startDate,endDate,duration));
             } break;
         }
     }
 }
}
```

Всего у меня 6 классов моделей, есть один родительский абстрактный их класс

```
package Models;

public abstract class Errors {
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;
    private int duration;

    public Errors(String startDate,String endDate,int duration) {
        this.startDate=startDate;
        this.endDate=endDate;
        this.duration=duration;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

Теперь надо сделать из них базу данных с такими же таблицами как и модели называются

Answer (score 0):

Для решения поставленной задачи проще всего использовать какой-то движек ORM (то есть отображения объектов в отношения). Вы можете задействовать **hibernate** или **Spring ORM**. Первый вариант потащит за собой меньше зависимостей.